# Angular $state.go {reload: true} shouldn't reinitialize the abstract parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-route for navigation.
I have father state called **main**, it's an `abstract` state (the url: */main*) and child states **products** and **users** (urls: */main/products* and */main/users*).

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main/products");
    $stateProvider
      .state("main", {
        url:"/main",
        templateUrl: "main.html",
        abstract: true,
        controller: "MainCtrl",
      })
      .state("main.products", {
        templateUrl: "products.html",
        controller: "productsCtrl",
      })
      .state("main.users", {
        templateUrl: "users.html",
        controller: "usersCtrl",
      })
  }
]);
```

And here my controllers:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$state) {
  console.log("I'm Main controller")

  $scope.goToProduct = function()
  {
    //$state.go("main.products",{})
    $state.go("main.products",{},{reload:true})
  }

  $scope.goToUsers = function()
  {
    //$state.go("main.users",{})
    $state.go("main.users",{},{reload:true})
  }

});

app.controller('usersCtrl', function() {
  console.log("I'm users controller")

});

app.controller('productsCtrl', function() {
  console.log("I'm products controller")
});
```

The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li style="cursor:pointer"  ng-click="goToProduct()">Click for products</li>
  <li style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="goToUsers()">Click for users</li>
</ul>

<br>
<div style="font-size:28px" ui-view></div>
```

As you can see, I'm using:
    **$state.go("main.products",{},{reload:true})**
for navigation

When I'm clicking on users/products on the menu the `MainCtrl` **reinitialize**!!
It's because the `{reload:true}`.

My questions:
1) Why the "father" state controller also reinitialize on each click?
2) I need an **elegant** solution to *avoid* the `MainCtrl` to **reinitialize**!

Here is the complete example - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G4wsPSh3tosMcElEMXKq?p=preview)  please look at the console.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to force reload (using the param `{reload:true}`) ?

Comment: I have my reasons, I have to use it in my application, of course without it everithing works perfectly

Comment: *sigh* You're asking for a solution, and you won't explain your full intent. As such, my answer to your first question is "Because the UI Router devs say that's how it should work. ( http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state )" My answer to your second question is, "Not enough info provided, even after it was requested. Good Luck."

Comment: I don't understand, my question it's very simple! I need to use {reload: true} because I need to refresh all the data from the server on each click. How can I overcome the problem when I have to (!!!!!) use {reload:true}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Update your ui-router to newer version (0.2.14 at least)
2. Change `$state.go` call to something like this `$state.go("main.users",{},{reload: "main.users"})`

Since ui-router 0.2.14 you can pass string as `reload` value - ui router will refresh state that matches to passed string and all its children.

Comment: 2) Your solution it's working for me!!! Still I don't understand why Angular team decided to reload also the abstract stae on {reload:true}

Answer (score 2):

the reload: true option will reload  current and parent states (basically from your current state to the highest level state). However, if you specify reload option with state name. it only reload the state that you put in and its all children state. This is straight from the doc