# call $state.go in modal angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have add in the controller of my modal an $state.go on my submit button function , at the first time it is invocked but when i try to open again the modal and submit it another time the $state.go didn't invocked.

ModalCtrler.js

```
$scope.addElet= function(){
  ------ 
  $state.go('state1',{OBJ: OBJ});   
}
```

the modal is defined in my run app.js:

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $modal,$state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState,toParams) {
    if (toState.name == 'addPopup') {

            $modal.open({
                templateUrl : 'add.html',
                controller : 'ModalCtrler',
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false,


            });

            event.preventDefault();

        } 

    }

}
```

the modal is called when i click in ui-serf :

```
<a ui-sref="addPopup({OBJ: OBJ})">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add pull-right">ADD</button>
</a>
```

Am i missing somthing in my code? anu idea?

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved by relaoding the state:

```
 $state.go('state1', {OBJ: OBJ}, { "reload": 'state1''});
```

Thanks to [link stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285018/angular-state-go-reload-true-shouldnt-reinitialize-the-abstract-father-cont)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is:

You do nothing with modal before you call `$state.go('state1',{OBJ: OBJ});`

Try to *hide* it and only after call `$state.go`

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl : 'add.html',
            controller : 'ModalCtrler',
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
        });
```

and something like:

```
$scope.addElet= function(){
  $modalInstance.close();  // or $modalInstance.dismiss();
  $state.go('state1',{OBJ: OBJ});   
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution , the same thing it doesn't not invoked.

Comment: yes, i reached it, but it doesn't enter in the controller of its state= state1, as the state didn't changed

Comment: @selma well, so this is a right behavior , can you clarify ?

Comment: Usually when calling the state.go it must change the state , here it doesn't changed.

Comment: i tried this one $state.go('state1', {OBJ: OBJ}, { "reload": true }); but it enter two times on each submit of the modal